# How do I update all computers in my home from my computer on a routine schedule?

Tags: upgrade, updates, multiple-users

My wife, daughters, and I have four computers using Ubuntu in our home, two on 16.04, two on 16.10, all wired to the same router. Is there an easy way to keep them all current on Ubuntu updates/upgrades?  I would like to avoid the apt-get manual drill for each of the computers

Comment: install unattended-upgrades

Comment: Do you mean backup update patch for offline use?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

**A.** Manually configure the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file and the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` via the `unattended-upgrades` package which you can check if its installed with:

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep unattended-upgrades
```

if its not installed, install:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

**B.** Using the `Softwware and Updates` tools

**Option 1:**

1. Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` to suit your needs:

   - configure unattended-upgrades(other configurations are present in the file):

     ```
     Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
         "Ubuntu xenial-security";
         "Ubuntu xenial-updates";
     };
     ```
   - Certain packages can also be blacklisted and therefore will not be automatically updated

     ```
     Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
          "vim";
          "libc6";
          "libc6-dev";
          "libc6-i686";
     };
     ```
2. To enable **automatic updates**, edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` and set the appropriate apt configuration options:

   ```
   APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
   APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
   APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
   APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
   ```

   - Meaning:

     - `1`: updated everyday,
     - `7`: updated every week

**Note:** The results of unattended-upgrades will be logged to `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`

**Option 2:**

1. Access the `Software and Updates` tools from `dash`:
2. In the `Updates tab`:

   - In the *When there are security updates* select: `DOwnload ans Install Automatically` option

[image]

- when asked for password, supply it

**Information:** Option 1 gives you more fine grained control of the whole process.

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html